# Remove Element in Array C++, Duplicates another Elemen

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm working on a school project and getting stuck on the best way to remove an element from an array. Unfortunately, the project requirements don't allow us to utilize vectors. I'm able to get rid of the element I need to (A3) but then when my code runs it's bringing up the last element in it's place instead of just shifting everything forward one. The project requirements are very specific and only allow me to have the studentID as the input for the function.

Here's what the results show after the function(notice A5 is now in 2 and 4):

```
Student ID   First Name  Last Name   Email Address   Age     Days In Courses     Degree Program
A1  John    Smith   John1989@gm ail.com 20  30,35,40    Security
A2  Suzan   Erickson    Erickson_1990@gmailcom  19  50,30,40    Network
A5  Dyllan  Hackett dhack27@gmail.com   30  14,4,25 Software
A4  Erin    Black   Erin.black@comcast.net  22  50,58,40    Security
A5  Dyllan  Hackett dhack27@gmail.com   30  14,4,25 Software
```

What I need it to show:

```
Student ID   First Name  Last Name   Email Address   Age     Days In Courses     Degree Program
A1  John    Smith   John1989@gm ail.com 20  30,35,40    Security
A2  Suzan   Erickson    Erickson_1990@gmailcom  19  50,30,40    Network
A4  Erin    Black   Erin.black@comcast.net  22  50,58,40    Security
A5  Dyllan  Hackett dhack27@gmail.com   30  14,4,25 Software
```

Here is the code that I'm trying, any help is appreciated! Going crazy trying different things.

roster.cpp

```
//
//  roster.cpp
//  DyllanHackett_C867
//
//  Created by Dyllan Hackett on 4/28/23.

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>
#include "roster.h"
#include "student.h"
#include "degree.h"

using namespace std;


// Remove student_ID
void Roster::remove(string studentID){
    int j;
    int found = 0;
    int tot = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (classRosterArray[i]->getStudentID() == studentID) {
            for (j=i; j <(tot -1);j++) {
                classRosterArray[j] = classRosterArray[j + i];
                found++;
                i--;
                tot--;
            }
        }
    }
    if (found == 0)
        cout << "StudentID not found in roster.\n";
    else
            cout << "StudentID removed.\n";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your program with a debugger?

Comment: Arrays are fixed size, so in a strict sense, you cannot remove elements from them. What you can do is keep track of which entries are currently in use. So you have 2 quantities:  capacity and numberInUse. It seems that you are using `index` to track the number in use - sometimes. But you aren't always maintaining it (e.g. in remove) and you are sometimes using dataTable in its place, though dataTable seems to represent capacity rather than elements in use in your code. Sort out these two concepts and handle them consistently and it should fix (at least a good part of) this problem.

Comment: @AviBerger Literally a lifesaver, just needed someone else to point out what I'd been staring out for too long. That makes total sense to utilize the index instead. I had gotten almost through the whole project and realized they don't allow vectors so I kind of had a mashed up code so completely forgot about using that. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Dyl *Unfortunately, the project requirements don't allow us to utilize vectors* -- FYI, the `std::vector` class has been officially part of C++ for **25 years** now.  I bet that this is older than most of the people in your class.  It really makes no sense whatsoever in this day and age to not use vector, unless the assignment is for you to create your own vector class (which your assignment is not about -- it is to maintain a school roster).  It's restrictions like this is why so many students drop C++, and instead go to python, C# or some other language.

Answer (score 0):

To move everything over one in a sequence, the code should read something like `arr[i] = arr[i + 1]`, which I am pretty sure you know already.

So, try putting some output statements for the indices that you are manipulating in the inner loop of the remove function to prove (or disprove) to yourself that you are doing something like the code above.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (classRosterArray[i]->getStudentID() == studentID) {
            for (j=i; j <(tot -1);j++) {
                classRosterArray[j] = classRosterArray[j + i];
                found++;
                i--;
                tot--;
            }
        }
    }
```